# AIX 7.1 .kshrc ignored

Tags: aix, ksh

I've created .kshrc file in my home directory, but all my custom settings are ignored. ENV variable is not set. How can I force ksh to read .kshrc?

Here is my .kshrc:

set -o emacs

export PATH=$PATH:/home/ibykov/bin:/usr/vacpp/bin

PS1="ibykov@host:${PWD##*/}\$"

Comment: Could you please post your .kshrc file here?

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below line into your .`profile`.

```
  export ENV=$HOME/.kshrc
```